# Arduino with GTK/CAIRO

Tags: c++, gtk, arduino, libraries, arduino-ide

I'm trying to create a GUI (User station kind) and use functions defined in the [arductoper](https://code.google.com/p/arducopter/) arduino library like the AP_Motors and the sensor data. Right now, the GUI is stand-alone and compiles with GTK as an included library:

```
g++ gui.cpp -o ucs `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

The arduino sketch is also standalone and has its own loop() function.

The question is, how do I include the arduino code & functions into my GUI code and compile it successfully? I've tried several things but it hasn't compiled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand.

The two programs will be on differnt machines right? So your GUI program will run on a desktop, and send serial data to Arduino. The arduino must understand the serail commands and send back data.

There are serval ways to use serail port in c++, none of them are easy.

The ardiuno code and the GTK code cannot be compiled together (they run on differnt machines).

Comment: I'm sorry, Looks like I got confused while writing this question. Is there a specific library I need to use for interacting with serial ports in c++?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

the boost lib are pretty good, but I have not used this one.

http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/  (this is some random serail library)
you could re-ask stackoverflow with the serial tag,